# How to proceed with using Moveit if you're not working on a PR2?

Tags: ros, moveit, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started looking into Moveit while using Kinova's robotic arms (Jaco Research edition). Will the steps described in the [tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#URDF) be similar for them?

If not, what points should I keep in mind when I start working on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64236/how-to-proceed-with-using-moveit-if-you%27re-not-working-on-a-pr2?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, just go through the whole tutorial.
After you have finished the assistant you have to manually create some yaml and launch files.
See my config for reference: [jaco_moveit_copy](https://github.com/fivef/JacoROS/tree/master/jaco_moveit_config)

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-06-09**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on 2014-02-03**:
That link text is broken :(

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2014-02-05**:
Link fixed, complete Jaco package added.

**Comment by [filipm](https://answers.ros.org/users/21332/filipm/) on 2015-01-09**:
Hi, can you reupload the text please. I am having problems setting up moveit.

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2015-02-24**:
Link fixed, again. Damed link ^^